# Apache 2.4 .htaccess Basic auth bypass by Request_URI

Tags: php, basic-authentication, silex, apache2.4

I have a PHP app running with Silex which is protected with basic auth but I need a section of the app to not ask for a password. I can do this in Apache 2.2 but it doesn't seem to work with 2.4. Here's my .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/register noauth=1
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Auth"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```

I know Apache 2.4 has a different way of doing this, anyone know how?

Comment: this page answers this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: google is the shilzele

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I fixed it like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /register noauth=1
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Auth"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
<RequireAny>
    Require env noauth
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```